# Haskell finding the length of a list from another equation

Tags: list, haskell

So I have an equation that returns a list given an int. I want to put that into another equation to see if the length is either of length one or two and return True if it is of length one and False if it is not.

```
con :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
con getList x
    | length x == 1 = True
    | otherwise     = False
```

Here's the closest I could get but it throws the error

```
ERROR - Cannot find "show" function for:
*** Expression : con 3
*** Of type    : [Int] -> Bool
```

Comment: What do you use `getST` for?

Comment: Did you type in `con 3` directly into Hugs?  You can't "print" a function, you have to provide it full arguments, so you could instead do `con 3 [1, 2, 3]` and it would print out `False`.  As a side note, I would recommend grabbing GHC from the Haskell Platform instead of Hugs.  Hugs has been deprecated for several years now.  While its error messages can be somewhat easier to read than GHC's, the latter has far more features, the error messages contain more information, and there are a plethora of language extensions that Hugs does not support.

Comment: Are you intending for the first argument of `con` to be a *function*? That is, `con :: (Int -> [Int]) -> Bool`?

Answer (score 5):

### The cause of the error

The error is caused by the fact that your `con` has the type:

```
 Int -> [Int] -> Bool
```

which means that it needs *two* arguments (of type `Int` and list of `Int`s respectively) to return a boolean.

Now, the expression `con 3` just applies `3` to `con` (supplying one argument), returning a function that takes a list of `Int`s and returns `Bool`.

This function has type `[Int] -> Bool` and functions do not have a `Show` instance (~cannot be printed on the screen).

### What you probably meant

You don't seem to need `getST` so you can just use:

```
con :: [a] -> Bool
con = (== 1) . length
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40ed5adac3df796f)

to have a function that given a list returns a bool so that: if the length of the list is `1` then the return value is `True` and `False` otherwise.

If you just want to pass the length of the list, then things get even simpler:

```
con :: Int -> Bool
con = (== 1)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/643167d1fe4d0ff4)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other interpretation that you probably just need a function that works with a list directly but in case you intended for the first argument to `con` to be a *function* of type `Int -> [Int]`, and then you want `con` to check whether the result of that function, applied to an `Int` argument, ends up having length 1, then you could do this:

```
con :: (Int -> [Int]) -> Int -> Bool
con f = (== 1) . length . f
```

Now suppose you have a different function that produces a list of `Int`s from a given `Int`. Maybe the length of the output is different depending on whether the input is even or odd:

```
getList :: Int -> [Int]
getList x
    | odd x = [x, x, x]
    | otherwise = [x]
```

Then we can check whether the output will have length 1 or not using `con`:

```
con getList 3 -- Will be False
con getList 2 -- Will be True
```